# librpm - How to verify the signature key of an installed package

Tags: c, linux, redhat, rpm

I would like to programmatically check if a RPM package is (1) signed (has a signature) and (2) the key used to sign is trusted.

```
[root]$ rpm -qi setup
Name        : setup
Signature   : RSA/SHA1, Wed 02 Oct 2013 05:15:22 AM MDT, Key ID 0946

[root]$ rpm -qi testing
Name        : testing
Signature   : (none)
```

I'm browsing the librpm API but I don't see any public methods allowing signature verification on already installed packages.

```
# This requires a file descriptor
rpmcli.h:rpmVerifySignatures

# This also requires a file descriptor
rpmlib.h:rpmReadPackageFile
```

Digging further I see:

```
# This uses a callback `qva_showPackage` which gives (QVA_t, rpmts, Header)
rpmcli.h:rpmcliVerify
```

But I cannot seem to get RPM tags (RPMTAG_SHA1HEADER) from the Header passed in by the callback. If I could get these tags then it would make sense to call into `rpmpgp.h:pgpVerifySig` to verify the signature.

**Edit:**

I see the bulk of the signature verification work is done in a static method `rpmchecksig.c:rpmpkgVerifySigs` which is only available through `rpmcli.h:rpmVerifySignatures`. But this method requires a file descriptor. Is there a way to get a FD from an already installed package to be able to use this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPM will verify header-only signatures when retrieving from an rpmdb if enabled through various mode-specific %_vsflags* settings. See /usr/lib/rpm/macros for values.

You will see the verification if you do, say, "rpm -Vvv bash". You can also enable the header-only signature verification on --query (or other) rpm modes by changing specific macros.

There is a means (but not a specific call) to retrieve the header plaintext, the header-only signature, and the pubkey if you wish to verify external to rpm.

Comment: Specific answers to your questions: 1) rpm header-only signatures are appended to installed headers and can be retrieved through headerGet(). See the tags being used in /usr/lib/rpm/rpmpopt. There is no way to verify header+payload signatures once the payload is discarded.

Comment: 2) The concept of "trusted" in rpm is exactly the same as importing the pubkey. Unlike gnupg, there is no trust metric packet appended to an imported public key. One can add a short table listing "trusted" keys and retrieve the signing pub key id if necessary, See the --info post alias in /usr/lib/rpm/rpmpopt for details.

Comment: Understood, thank you for clarifying this. Are there vsflags that check for the existence of a signature? I am adding VERIFY_SIGNATURE to qva_flags and running verification but it passes on installed RPM's that have no signature (`Signature   : (none)`). I'm guessing I have to override qva_showPackage will a callback of my own and see if the RPM signature opts exists, if not, fail verification. Is that right? (DSAHEADER, RSAHEADER, SIGGPG, SIGPGP)

Comment: Yes. You will need to check for the existence of one of the header-only signature tags: RPMTAG_DSAHEADER or RPMTAG_RSAHEADER. See the --info popt (not "post") alias. Don't bother with the RPMTAG_SIGGPG and RPMTAG_SIGPGP header+payload signatures: they cannot be verified after the payload in the *.rpm is discarded.

Comment: How to verify RPMTAG_RSAHEADER using c code, is there any rpm api for same ?